# How to show data having varchar(max) as data type in Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

i am using crystal report 8.5 and sql server 2008 R2. I have print a column value whose data type is varchar(max). But when i try to print this coulmn value in crystal report, some of the data is not displayed. only half data gets displayed.
How can I print whole data on crystal report. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per I know and If I understand problem correctly, the maximum length of string crystal report supports (per database text field) is 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Crystal Reports that mistakenly identifies `varchar(max)` as `varchar(255)`. You can use `varchar(8000)` which should be correctly identified by crystal however there's no way I've found to allow over 7999 characters.